# Ridiculously slow read/write between two SSDs (Linux)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, performance, linux-mint

So I have a Kingston SSD ([120Gb HyperX 3K; SH103S3/120G](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/sh103s3_en.pdf)) that is about two years old and just picked up a new Kingston SSD ([240GB SSDNow V300; SV300S37A/240G](http://www.kingston.com/us/ssd/v#sv300s3)) to go along with it. I’m trying to transfer data over, except the read/write speeds are ridiculously slow. Like sometimes it starts at 150Mb/s, sometimes it starts at 25Mb/s, but either way it’s under 10Mb/s within a minute. For large transfers > 5Gb it seems to stabilize around 2Mb/s.

The old drive benchmarks to around 300Mb/s for both read and write and the new drive to 400Mb/s. Looks like it’s a serious problem with sustained transfers.

I’m on Linux, both drives formatted to Ext4, and using a 4 year old motherboard ([ASUS M5A99X EVO](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A99X_EVO/)); not sure if it would be more software or hardware related. I believe they’re in SATA III although not 100% sure.

Anyone have ideas as to what might be causing the slowdown or how I can improve it?

It actually seems like it’s a software limitation somewhere in Linux, writing my own file transfer script using shutil in python I can get a sustained 150-350Mb/s no problem.

```
Linux version 3.16.0-38-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.8.2 
(Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu

Fresh install of Linux Mint Rafaela 64
Mate 1.10.0-1
Nemo 1.1.2?
```

Comment: How are you trying to transfer the data across ? Maybe some other software is gettng in the way, or you have fauly hardware ?

Comment: I'm getting slow speeds using the standard copy/paste functionality through the file manager (nemo). No other software is reading from or writing to the old disk, and very minimal I/O on the new disk. I doubt it's a hardware problem as I'm able to get normal speeds through other methods.

Comment: I know some slowdown is expected, but after some trial and error with alternative methods it is much much MUCH slower than it is physically capable of.

Comment: You are aware ext4 and with other filesystems is not the greatest for  small file large quantity transfers I hope.  what other methods have you tried exactly ? rsync  scp ftp or  just  the ``dd`` given by  Jake Gould and  stand  cp <source> <dest> ?